# CKEditor setData is not loading the below record

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel, ckeditor

Article Record (body part) that I am trying to display in the CKEditor from the mysql database in order to make an update/edit form:-

```
<p><a href="https://gigaom.com/analyst/crawford-tim/">Tim Crawford</a></p>

<h3>How to Get This Report</h3>

<h2>Option 1</h2>

<p><strong>Purchase&nbsp;just&nbsp;this report for $495.00</strong></p>

<p><a href="https://gigaom.com/report/artificial-intelligence-for-the-enterprise-a-primer-on-ai-use-in-the-enterprise/?add-to-cart=953946&amp;quantity=1&amp;quick_buy=1">Order</a></p>

<h2>Option 2</h2>

<p><strong>Subscribe to Gigaom Research and get access to:</strong></p>

<ul>
    <li>This report.</li>
    <li>Our collection of 1,700+ other reports written by leading analysts.</li>
    <li>All new reports which come out monthly.</li>
    <li>The full video of Gigaom events, future and past.</li>
    <li>Our webinars, infographics and other valuable information.</li>
</ul>

<p><strong>$995/y</strong></p>

<ul>
    <li>Email address</li>
    <li>Company name</li>
</ul>

<p>Subscribe now</p>

<p><strong>Required</strong>&nbsp;Your email address is your sign-in ID for Gigaom. By continuing, you are agreeing to our&nbsp;<a href="https://gigaom.com/terms-of-service/">Terms of Service</a>&nbsp;and&nbsp;<a href="https://gigaom.com/privacy-policy/">Privacy Policy</a>.</p>

<ul>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?counturl=https%3A%2F%2Fgigaom.com%2Freport%2Fartificial-intelligence-for-the-enterprise-a-primer-on-ai-use-in-the-enterprise%2F&amp;text=Artificial+Intelligence+for+the+Enterprise%3A+A+Primer+on+AI+Use+in+the+Enterprise&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fgigaom.com%2Freport%2Fartificial-intelligence-for-the-enterprise-a-primer-on-ai-use-in-the-enterprise%2F&amp;via=Gigaom">Tweet</a>&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?text=Artificial+Intelligence+for+the+Enterprise%3A+A+Primer+on+AI+Use+in+the+Enterprise&amp;u=https%3A%2F%2Fgigaom.com%2Freport%2Fartificial-intelligence-for-the-enterprise-a-primer-on-ai-use-in-the-enterprise%2F">Share</a>&nbsp;</li>
    <li><a href="http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&amp;source=Gigaom&amp;summary=&amp;title=Artificial+Intelligence+for+the+Enterprise%3A+A+Primer+on+AI+Use+in+the+Enterprise&amp;url=https%3A%2F%2Fgigaom.com%2Freport%2Fartificial-intelligence-for-the-enterprise-a-primer-on-ai-use-in-the-enterprise%2F">Post</a></li>
</ul>

<h2>Analysis</h2>

<p>The world of Artificial Intelligence (AI) is growing at an unprecedented rate. This report provides a broad look at how enterprises leverage AI in meaningful ways. This report includes data from Gigaom&rsquo;s recent AI survey, insights from our recent AI Conference, and personal experience working with corporate enterprises on their AI journey.</p>

<p>Gigaom&rsquo;s AI survey and conference focused on what enterprises are doing today versus the potential that AI brings. In addition, both efforts focused predominantly on the corporate enterprise versus new entrants to the corporate world. The intent focused on a wide margin of companies that are often overlooked, yet represent most corporations in existence today. The Gigaom AI Survey (n=303), specifically targeted enterprise companies with at least 1,000 people and those whom are&nbsp;<em>actually working</em>&nbsp;with AI today.</p>


<h3><a href="https://giganom.com/report/artificial-intelligence-for-the-enterprise-a-primer-on-ai-use-in-the-enterprise/#toggle">Table of Contents</a></h3>

<ol>
    <li>Summary</li>
    <li>Overview of AI</li>
</ol>
```

I am making a blog post, how can I retrieve any data given in the database in the ckeditor.

Code in my javascript in Laravel to retrieve the above data from database:

```
  var html_body_{{$admin_post->id}} = "<?php echo str_replace(array("\r\n", "\n", "\r"), ' ', $admin_post->body); ?>";
                            CKEDITOR.instances['body_{{$admin_post->id}}'].setData(html_body_{{
admin_post->id}});
```

Comment: missing **`$`** in **`setData(html_body_{{admin_post->id}});`**